# How to define and use a "array of structure" in nasm-syntax asm code?

Tags: winapi, assembly, nasm, masm, seh

So basically I am dealing with a pseudo asm code on Win32, and I am trying to make it re-assemble.

In the code, I see data structure like this:

```
errtable    errentry <1, 16h>
            errentry <2, 2>
            errentry <3, 2>
            errentry <4, 18h>
            errentry <5, 0Dh>
            .....
```

And in the .text section, I see code like this:

```
cmp     eax, dword ptr errtable.oscode[ecx*8]
mov     eax, errtable.errnocode[ecx*8]
```

Basically asm code/data like those above can not be directly re-assembled by NASM/MASM on windows 32 bit. So I have to adjust this code/data...

I searched on line and find the definition of the data structure in C:

```
struct errentry {
    unsigned long oscode;           /* OS return value */
    int errnocode;  /* System V error code */
};

static struct errentry errtable[] = {
    {  ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION,       EINVAL    },  /* 1 */
    {  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND,         ENOENT    },  /* 2 */
    {  ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND,         ENOENT    },  /* 3 */
    {  ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES,    EMFILE    },  /* 4 */
    {  ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED,          EACCES    },  /* 5 */
    {  ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE,         EBADF     },  /* 6 */
    {  ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED,          ENOMEM    },  /* 7 */
    {  ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY,      ENOMEM    },  /* 8 */
    .........
```

So my question is : How to modify the asm code/data to make it re-assemble?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both [nasm](/questions/tagged/nasm) and [masm](/questions/tagged/masm) tagged, which do you need?  I am sure this can be done in NASM with some sort of macro, but in MASM it is a breeze.

```
ENOENT      equ 2
EBADF       equ 9
ENOMEM      equ 12
EACCES      equ 13
EINVAL      equ 22
EMFILE      equ 24

errentry struc
    oscode      dd  ?
    ernocode    dd  ?
errentry ends

.data
errtable    errentry    <ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION, EINVAL>, \
                        <ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, ENOENT>, \
                        <ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND, ENOENT>, \
                        <ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES, EMFILE>, \
                        <ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, EACCES>, \
                        <ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE, EBADF>, \
                        <ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED, ENOMEM>, \
                        <ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY, ENOMEM>
                        ; ...
.code
start:

NextCode:
    cmp     eax, errtable.oscode[ecx * 8]
    jne     NotFound

    mov     eax, errtable.ernocode[ecx * 8]
    jmp     Next

NotFound:
    ; Err number not found, return something

Next:
```

And some test code: 
We will change the registers around so we don't need to save them around `printf`

```
include masm32rt.inc

ENOENT      equ 2
EBADF       equ 9
ENOMEM      equ 12
EACCES      equ 13
EINVAL      equ 22
EMFILE      equ 24

errentry struc
    oscode      dd  ?
    ernocode    dd  ?
errentry ends

.data
fmtint      db  "OS Code = %d, Err Code = %d", 13, 10, 0
fmtstr      db  "OS Code %d NOT FOUND!!!", 13, 10, 0

errtable    errentry    <ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION, EINVAL>, \
                        <ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, ENOENT>, \
                        <ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND, ENOENT>, \
                        <ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES, EMFILE>, \
                        <ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, EACCES>, \
                        <ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE, EBADF>, \
                        <ERROR_ARENA_TRASHED, ENOMEM>, \
                        <ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY, ENOMEM>
                        ; ...
errtable_len    equ ($ - errtable) / 8

.code
start:

    mov     edi, 1
    xor     ebx, ebx
NextCode:
    cmp     edi, errtable.oscode[ebx * 8]
    jne     NotFound

    invoke  crt_printf, offset fmtint, errtable.oscode[ebx * 8], errtable.ernocode[ebx * 8]
    jmp     Next

NotFound:
    ; Err number not found, return something 
    invoke  crt_printf, offset fmtstr, edi 


Next:
    inc     ebx
    inc     edi
    cmp     edi, 12 ; loop 3 more than our test array
    jne     NextCode

    inkey
    invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gunner, Thank you! I am using nasm and well, currently I am trying to bypass this problem...But still some issues ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892665/where-is-mtinit-ioinit-and-mtterm-defined-on-win32 ... I don't know why someone negative my question...

Comment: I should have follow your solution, haha